# Создание браузерной игры "крестики-нолики"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Задача: разработать браузерную онлайн игру "крестики-нолики".

Есть веб-страница с подключенной базой данных mysql,для регистрации пользователей. Нужно написать сервер на php,который принимает запросы от клиента (клиент это веб-страница как я понял) с помощью Ajax и JSON. После регистрации,пользователь переходит в меню,где можно выбрать одну из начатых игр, продолжить свою игру либо создать новую игру. Если пользователь выбрал создать новую игру,то он каким-то образом подключается к другому игроку и переходит на пустое игровое поле где может ставить только крестики,а второй игрок - только нолики. Если пользователь выбрал одну из начатых игр или решил продолжить свою,то на экран выводится состояние чужой игры или его,соответственно.

Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Какие функции будет выполнять сервер? База данных, где хранится вся информация об играх разве не является сервером?
2. Какие стоит создать таблицы в базе? Пока думаю такие: Игроки(id,логин),Игры(id,название игры),Поле(id,?)
3. Как вывести список существующих игр из базы в html,чтобы можно было перейти в нужную игру?
4. Как я понимаю,игроки взаимодействуют на одном поле с помощью одного id поля,а крестик/нолик назначается им случайно,но в какой из таблиц?
5. Как сделать,чтобы один игрок ждал,пока ходит другой?

Есть такой план: В базе будет записываться состояние каждой клетки поля(пустое,крестик,нолик). При нажатии игрока по пустой клетке,в базе будет прописываться значение "крестик" с помощью Ajax поле будет обновляться и на клетке будет ставиться крестик.

Подскажите,пожалуйста,правильно ли я рассуждаю и ,если можно сделать все намного проще,но с теми же средствами,я бы хотел узнать как. Времени на этот проект очень мало и подробно разбираться нет возможности.Не могли бы вы дать какие-нибудь полезные советы или ссылки,это бы мне очень помогло.

Comment: по #1. сервер отдает html- и другие файлы по запросу. а также обрабатывает пересылку данных между игроками. а также передает и получает данные от субд.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

1. Посмотрите на трехзвенную архитектуру веб-приложений. Сервер и БД не являются одним и тем же. Сервер занимается обработкой пользовательских запросов и принимает решения, когда как БД просто хранит информацию и обработкой не занимается.
2. Вам понадобится аутентификация и регистрация, а значит таблица для логинов-паролей + возможно таблица о доп.сведениях.

Структура:

```
    UserAuthentification
        ID
        Login
        Password

    User
        ID
        ... //Name, Lastname, etc
```

Вам понадобятся данные об играх и столах

```
    Board
        ID
        UserX  //id пользователя играющего за X
        UserO  //id пользователя играющего за O
        Status //открыта(1 игрок в комнате), начата(2 игрока), закончена
```

А так же сделанные на ней ходы:

```
    Moves
        BoardID
        Step     //Номер хода
        Location //Куда походил пользователь {1-9}
        XorO     //Чем заполнено поле, X или O
```

3. Взять и вывести из БД с помощью сервера и Ajax, о взаимодействии PHP+MySQL можно почитать в интернете.
4. Рандом для выбора, далее заносим пользователя в поле UserX или UserO таблицы Board
5. Опять же на стороне сервера проверить, может игрок ходить или нет и уведомлять по Ajax об этом.

В любом случае, сначала изучите как работают такие приложения на примере трехзвенной архитектуры HTML+PHP+MySQL и потом на бумажке продумайте Интерфейс, Структуру БД и Сервер.